# Controller change mechanics

Tags: magic-the-gathering

How do abilities work when card controller changes?
Playing MTGA I saw these:

Taking control of [Rekindling Phoenix](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rekindling%20Phoenix) and having it die creates the egg for the new controller, which makes sense to me.

But taking control of a creature with [Rogue's Gloves](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=447380) and damaging opponent lets HIM draw a bonus card, not the creature's current controller.

Is that a bug in MTGA or some strange rule?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are both correct. You see a difference because the abilities are on different permanents.

When you take control of an opponent's creature that is equipped with Rogue's Gloves, the Rogue's Gloves stays attached to the creature but the equipment itself is still controlled by the opponent, and the triggered ability is on the equipment. So, when the creature deals combat damage to the opponent, the opponent controls the Gloves' triggered ability and they get to draw the card.

> 301.5d An Equipment’s controller is separate from the equipped creature’s controller; the two need not be the same. Changing control of the creature doesn’t change control of the Equipment, and vice versa. Only the Equipment’s controller can activate its abilities. However, if the Equipment grants an ability to the equipped creature (with “gains” or “has”), the equipped creature’s controller is the only one who can activate that ability.

Comment: Note the difference between the wording on Rogue's Gloves and [Curious Obsession](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=439692) - if you were to gain control of a creature with Curious Obsession attached *you* would draw the card instead of your opponent.

Comment: Thank you both. The Curious Obsession hint is spot on, I think that's the main thing that confused me, seeing it behave one way then Rogue's Gloves in the opposite way. The Equipment ability vs the Equipment-granted Creature ability is an important distinction I didn't realize.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus what's the difference in wording on Rogue's Gloves and Curious Obsession? They seem to read the same to me.

Comment: @Allure  Curious Obsession grants the ability to the creature, while the Rogue's Gloves keep the ability for itself, merely being triggered by the creature.